# Flask with dash app, why WGSI can't import modules?

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash, importerror

I'm trying to add dash instance to a flask app, but struggle with WGSI import.

WGSI doesn't want to import the dash module while it's installed and works well when I run directly the file Flask_app.py.

The /var/www/pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py

```
import sys

# add your project directory to the sys.path
project_home = '/home/mysite'
if project_home not in sys.path:
    sys.path = [project_home] + sys.path

# import flask app but need to call it "application" for WSGI to work
from flask_app import app as application  # noqa
```

The /home/mysite/flask_app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import dash

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello from Flask!

# Set-up endpoint 1
app_1 = dash.Dash(name='app1', server=app, url_base_pathname='/app1/')
app_1.layout = html.H1('App 1')
```

The error:

```
Error running WSGI application
2021-12-14 16:16:26,591: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dash'
2021-12-14 16:16:26,591:   File "/var/www/pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2021-12-14 16:16:26,591:     from flask_app import app as application  # noqa
2021-12-14 16:16:26,591: 
2021-12-14 16:16:26,592:   File "/home/mysite/flask_app.py", line 5, in <module>
2021-12-14 16:16:26,592:     import dash
2021-12-14 16:16:26,592: ***************************************************
2021-12-14 16:16:26,592: If you're seeing an import error and don't know why,
2021-12-14 16:16:26,592: we have a dedicated help page to help you debug: 
2021-12-14 16:16:26,592: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/
2021-12-14 16:16:26,592: ***************************************************
```

EDIT: In fact it seems WGSI won't import any module, tried with pandas:

```
2021-12-14 16:47:51,730: Error running WSGI application
2021-12-14 16:47:51,734: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
2021-12-14 16:47:51,734:   File "/var/www/pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 17, in <module>
2021-12-14 16:47:51,734:     from flask_app import app as application  # noqa
2021-12-14 16:47:51,734: 
2021-12-14 16:47:51,735:   File "/home/mysite/flask_app.py", line 5, in <module>
2021-12-14 16:47:51,735:     import pandas
2021-12-14 16:47:51,735: ***************************************************
2021-12-14 16:47:51,735: If you're seeing an import error and don't know why,
2021-12-14 16:47:51,735: we have a dedicated help page to help you debug: 
2021-12-14 16:47:51,735: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/
2021-12-14 16:47:51,735: ***************************************************
```

Comment: You have a typo. You're trying to import a module `flask_app`, but you have a file called `Flask_app.py`.

Comment: Thank you for you help, but this file name is flask_app.py, I edited it in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what's happening is that you don't have an environment active when running the app that has `dash` and `pandas` installed.

You might have `dash` and `pandas` installed in an environment inside `/home/mysite`, but that doesn't mean when your execute `flask run` inside `/var/www` it automatically import those dependencies from your other environment.

I was able to get your code running by installing `dash` and `pandas` in an environment inside the folder `pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py` is in.

Comment: I have the same thoughts too but all the packages are installed in `var/www/ `. I just verified with `pip list --local` in the `var/www/` folder

Answer (score 0):

I was in the wrong environment, after installing all dependencies in the right on it works! Thanks